# How do I test if a CLLocationCoordinate2D is visible in the current MKMapView?

Tags: ios4, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have many pins on my map and I want to animate the callout for the most visible pin.  How can I check to see if the CLLocationCoordinate2D of a pin is visible or closest to the center?

Answer (score 3):

This might solve ur query

```
  MKMapPoint userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate);
    MKMapRect mapRect = _mapView.visibleMapRect;
    BOOL inside = MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapRect, userPoint);
```